# Como unir 3 queries de quantidades de registros diferentes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Preciso unir 3 *queries* com resultados e quantidades de registros diferentes em uma única consulta, usando o *Where* do fim do script como *Where* principal para todas as *queries*. Como posso fazer isto?

Tentei com o *Union*, mas ele não executa, exibindo erro sobre quantidade diferente de registros.

```
/*QUERY 1*/
/******QUERY PARA BUSCAR O PERCENTUAL DE PESSOAS NA FABRICA NO PERIODO******/
WITH somatorio AS (
SELECT (CONVERT(DECIMAL(4,2),(SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(4,2), COUNT(*)) FROM (SELECT PG_DATA FROM SPG010 WHERE YEAR(PG_DATA) = YEAR(sd3.D3_EMISSAO) AND MONTH(PG_DATA) = MONTH(sd3.D3_EMISSAO) AND PG_MAT = RA_MAT GROUP BY PG_DATA) as dias_trab) /26)) as presenca
FROM SRA010 AS sra

 WHERE  (RA_SITFOLH NOT IN ('D', 'A') OR RA_DEMISSA  > CAST(YEAR(sd3.D3_EMISSAO) AS VARCHAR)+CAST(REPLICATE('0', 2 - LEN(MONTH(sd3.D3_EMISSAO))) + RTrim(MONTH(sd3.D3_EMISSAO)) AS VARCHAR)+'31')
AND SUBSTRING(RA_CC,1,5) = SUBSTRING(sd3.D3_CC,1,5)
)
SELECT SUM(presenca) AS soma FROM somatorio

/*QUERY 2*/
/******QUERY PARA BUSCAR O CENTRO DE CUSTO E EMISSAO******/
SELECT SUBSTRING(ctt.CTT_CUSTO,1,5) AS CTT_CUSTO, CAST(MONTH(sd3.D3_EMISSAO) AS VARCHAR) + '/' + CAST(YEAR(sd3.D3_EMISSAO) AS VARCHAR) AS PERIODO, sd3.D3_EMISSAO,  

/*QUERY 3*/ 
/******SUBQUERY PARA BUSCAR A QUANTIDADE PRODUZIDA NO PERIODO******/
    (SELECT sum(sd3_sub1.D3_QUANT)
     FROM SD3010 AS sd3_sub1        
     WHERE sd3_sub1.D3_TM = sd3.D3_TM       
        AND YEAR(D3_EMISSAO) = YEAR(sd3.D3_EMISSAO)  AND MONTH(D3_EMISSAO) = MONTH(sd3.D3_EMISSAO)      
        AND sd3_sub1.D3_FILIAL = sd3.D3_FILIAL
        AND SUBSTRING(sd3_sub1.D3_CC,1,5) = SUBSTRING(sd3.D3_CC,1,5)
        AND sd3_sub1.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*') AS Producao


FROM SD3010 AS sd3

INNER JOIN CTT010 AS ctt ON (SUBSTRING(sd3.D3_CC,1,5) = SUBSTRING(ctt.CTT_CUSTO,1,5))

/*WHERE PRINCIPAL*/
WHERE sd3.D3_TM = '010'
    AND sd3.D3_LOCAL IN ('01','02')
    AND sd3.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*'
    AND sd3.D3_EMISSAO BETWEEN '20170101' and '20170131'
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(ctt.CTT_CUSTO,1,5), SUBSTRING(sd3.D3_CC,1,5),  YEAR(sd3.D3_EMISSAO), MONTH(sd3.D3_EMISSAO),  sd3.D3_FILIAL, sd3.D3_TM, sd3.D3_EMISSAO
```

O resultado deveria ser algo como abaixo, porém, só funciona quando deixo os valores fixos do *Where* da query1, ao invés de pegar as informações do Where:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: veja se tabelas temporárias não resolve seu problema. cria uma tabela temporária, preenche ela com o resultado dos selects e depois faz um select nela aplicando as condições que você precisa na clausula WHERE. dá uma olhada nesse artigo http://imasters.com.br/artigo/3727/sql-server/entendendo-tabelas-temporarias?trace=1519021197&source=single

Comment: @ThiagoAlessandro: É para colocar o resultado de cada consulta um abaixo do outro (concatenação vertical) ou para colocar lado a lado (concatenação horizontal)?

Comment: @JoséDiz seria o layout de uma consulta padrão: um campo ao lado do outro, e os outros registros logo abaixo, colocando novamente um campo ao lado do outro

Comment: @ThiagoAlessandro: Poderia acrescentar acima, na descrição do tópico, amostra de como é o resultado das 3 consultas, individualmente, e de como deseja o resultado ao final?

Comment: @JoséDiz Atualizado